# PHP/MySQL Select From Order statement not working the results correctly

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

Anybody have any idea why this query isn't working?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

I want the data to order backwards, from the highest value ID all the way to 1.

But it doesn't do that. It just orders them 1,2,3,4,5

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting in `ASC`ending order when you want to sort in `DESC`ending order. Try the following instead:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

If per chance, you want the 10 items with the lowest `ID`'s but want them in descending order, then you could use the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0, 10) ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple.

```
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

(ASC means ascending, DESC means descending).

Answer (score 0):

Change `ASC` to `DESC`.

That's "ascending" to "descending".

Answer (score 0):

Use DESC in your ORDER BY statement:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 10");`

Answer (score 0):

change your ASC to DESC like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 10